# Populating multiple fields with dynamic user meta

Tags: wordpress, gravityforms

I have a Wordpress site where each user is linked to an 'upline' user, with that upline user's ID stored in a custom meta field 'direct_upline'.

On a particular gravity form, I currently populate a hidden field with value of {user:direct_upline}.

For example, User A fills out the form. User A's direct_upline is User B. I would like to then populate User B's direct_upline, and so on (probable 10 levels deep).

Any idea how to most efficiently perform this? Below is a function to populate multiple fields in one function; I was thinking I may could do this in conjunction with $all_meta_for_user = get_user_meta( $user_id );

```
add_filter( 'gform_field_value', 'populate_fields', 10, 3 );
function populate_fields( $value, $field, $name ) {

    $values = array(
        'field_one'   => 'value one',
        'field_two'   => 'value two',
        'field_three' => 'value three',
    );

    return isset( $values[ $name ] ) ? $values[ $name ] : $value;
}
```